# How to safely remove Laravel Debugbar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application that was not developed by me. There is some weird bar at the bottom of each page, it is some type of Laravel debugger tool.

[image]

I believe it is stored in storage/debugger. Is there a safe way I can go about checking to see if this is actually it and if so can I delete this type of tool without it affecting the application? Does anybody know what this thing is if so any advice on how to remove this safely would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Method 01:** To completely turn off the debugger

In `.env`

```
APP_DEBUG=false # No error reporting at all
```

---

**Method 02:** Disable the debugger but  still wants to receive Errors (***Recommended way*)

In `.env`

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false # deguger is disabled, but error reporting works
```

---

**Method 03:** If ou want to remove *Debugbar completely

1. `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`
2. then in `config/app.php` remove `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class` if exist and in the facade `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class`
3. `php artisan cache:clear`

---

> **FYI:** Once you changed the values on `.env` and it didn't reflect, clear the config using `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan optimize:clear`

---

**Useful Links**

1. [Errors & Logging Laravel Docs 9.x](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#configuration)
2. [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: I have never accepted before, I did not know that was a thing :).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I understand your point, and that is good advice, but development has been completed! I was just getting rid of that debugbar.

Comment: Why would you use `APP_DEBUG=true` in production? That makes literally no sense. You want big stack traces of your application printed when errors occur? I think you're wanting to target `app_log_level` instead.

Comment: Thanks, still works this way in Laravel 10 too.

Answer (score 145):

Best option:

Add `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` to your `.env`

This has some advantage:

- The debugbar is totally disabled
- You can keep `APP_DEBUG=true`, hence still keep error details for local development
- It is not tracked by git

Comment: Don't forget to run `php artisan config:clear` after changing the `.env` entry

Answer (score 29):

Enabling/Disabling on run time.

You can enable or disable the debugbar during run time.

Add this into your `.env` file:

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED = FALSE
```

In runtime:

```
\Debugbar::enable();
\Debugbar::disable();
```

Or remove everything

`composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`

Comment: In case you found error where `Debugbar` class in not found, make sure to import it as
`use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;`

Answer (score 28):

**Remove Laravel Debugbar**

*- If you want to totally remove the package, then do these steps:*

1. `$ composer remove vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`
2. `$ composer update`

---

**Disable Laravel Debugbar**

**Option 1:** Via Env File

*- If you want disable the package, without it getting tracked by Git:*

1. Navigate to your `.env` file
2. And put `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED = FALSE`

**Option 2:** Via AppServiceProvider

*- From [@Ohgodwhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48220741/5881733)*

*- FYI: This will be tracked by Git. - [@Salam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6714319/salam)*

1. Navigate to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`
2. Put this code `\Debugbar::disable();`

   ```
   class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       public function boot()
       {
           \Debugbar::disable();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Disabling from `boot()` in `AppServiceProvider` will be tracked by git. FYI

Comment: this is what i want  `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED` env variable

Comment: I did it and now `AppServiceProvier` keep giving me error saying `''Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found`. I Just removed, why still trying to find it?

Answer (score 10):

You can execute `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` to permanently remove it.

Note you can also just disable the debug bar if you don't want it:

Just put `\Debugbar::disable();` in your `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: This seems like a permanent removal. I will keep this in mind for the future. I used Abdullas suggestion above because it was a bit faster :), Thank you for your advice and contribution.

Comment: The second one is much better if you don't want to use `debugbar ` temporarily but enable the `APP_DEBUG=true`.

Comment: This would not work if there is a `composer.lock` file present because `composer install` will use this instead, and will have been generated from an previous version of `composer.json`. You need to run `composer update` instead, which will use your modified `composer.json` and generate the `composer.lock` based on that. The idea is you run update in development and deploy the lock file then only ever use install in production. This way you are guaranteed the same version as in testing right down to the minor version. Also you don't need to manually delete anything from `vendor`.

Answer (score 7):

I am using this way:

In config/debugbar.php

```
'inject'          => false, // this remove Inject Debugbar in Response
```

In this way I am keeping .php error enable.

Another way is to disable completely.

```
 'enabled'         => false,
```

To enable just debug-bar and disable it for session and Ajax request

```
'enabled'         => true,
```

....

```
'storage'         => [
        'enabled'    => false, // DebugBar stores data for session/ajax requests.
```

or

```
 'capture_ajax'    => false,
```

Comment: This is great, but my question is why there is no debugbar.php in my config folder, is it something i have to add manually or is it supposed to be there since i'm using laravel 5.5 and have debugbar working in my sandbox server?

Answer (score 4):

I removed `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` from my `composer.json`.
When I wanted to do `composer install` or `composer update` or even `php artisan config:cache` I got error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
Class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found
```

If fact the solution was removing `boostrap/cache/config.php`, because `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` was cached (`php artisan config:cache` could not remove it)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**It needs to be also removed in the providers: `app/config/app.php`**

After:

1. `composer remove vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`
2. `composer update`

**remove the line:**

`Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider` in *app/config/app.php*.

Also these folders can be deleted:

- `app/config/packages/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/config.php`
- another Debugbar-related file somewhere under `app/storage/...`

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to remove the package, then do these steps:

$ `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` 
$ `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score -9):

Also can be removed adding this to your .css file

```
.phpdebugbar{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That not a good idea. The data will still be sent to the user which means everybody who has a look at the HTML will also be able to see what is going on in your backend.

Comment: Thanks, never thought about that !

Comment: Of all the ways you could have accomplished this, this is the absolute worst. All you're doing is hiding the bar, not preventing it from loading, so you're getting all the disadvantage of the debugbar's slow speed with none of its debugging advantage.